# ¿Como reemplazar cadena de string en C#?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

tengo un archivo JSON que cargo en una variable string, tiene el siguiente formato:

```
Datos:[{
  Prueba1: 'ejemplo',
  Nombre: 'Mu{0}oz Ramirez Manuel',
  Direccion: 'Rosal{1} {2}123'
},
{
  Prueba1: 'ejemplo',
  Nombre: 'Martinez Claudio',
  Direccion: 'Mi nro {2}123'
}]
```

lo que busco es reemplazar todos los {0}, {1} y {2} por ñ, í, #, que encuentre.

1. Es un archivo JSON de 44MB (muy grande)
2. string.Format no funciona debido a que no todos los JSON cumplen obligatoriamente con {0},{1}, {2}, algunos puede tener {0} y {2}, otro puede tener {1} y {2}, o los 3.
3. la función string Replace, me hace efecto solo en la primera ocurrencia, pero en un archivo de 44MB hay muchas más.
4. Lo más probable sea con Regex.replace, pero no logro conseguir el patrón (pattern) para reemplazar los {0} {1} {2} a las letras que corresponden.

¿Cómo podría reemplazar los {0} {1} y {2} por las letras que corresponden?
Gracias.!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! pero replace reemplaza todas las ocurrencias... porque decis que no anda?

Comment: la función string replace, solo me reemplaza la primera ocurrencia, y usar Regex.Replace no logro decifrar el patrón correcto para el reemplazo

Comment: la documentacion de la funcion dice que reemplaza todas las ocurrencias... nos mostras como lo probaste y el resultado?

Comment: Deberias agregar como lo hiciste, pero supongo que tenes un modelo de datos y lo recorres con un foreach y ahi deberias usar el regex

Comment: Hola, gracias, solucioné el problema con Replace, lo que hice fue recorrer línea por línea, eso solucionó el problema.! Saludos!